# neon:multiply and accumulate for 64 bit as IP & OP

Tags: arm, simd, neon, cortex-a

Is there any way to implement below logic in neon .
As I did not find any multiply and accumulate instruction for 64 bit input and output value .

```
int64x2_t result;
int64x2_t num1;
int64x2_t num2;

>> result + = num1*num2  <<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically two 64-bit values could result in a 128-bit result. That's why there are the following `int64*int32+int32` functions, but not one that takes two 64-bit input values.

```
int64x2_t vmlal_s32 (int64x2_t, int32x2_t, int32x2_t);
int64x2_t vqdmlal_s32 (int64x2_t, int32x2_t, int32x2_t);
```

If those don't work for you, then you'll need to use a scalar 64*64 operations followed by `vaddq_s64`.

Note: Visual Studio implements `_mul128`, `__umul128`, `_mulh`, and `__umulh` for all architectures including ARM for handling the full 64*64 = 128 bit scenario.